# VBA Replace in Excel "statement invalid outside type block"

Tags: vba, excel

Having a compile error, "Statement invalid outside Type block"

I'm trying to search column C for the string "Steel Structural" and if it is present, then replace it with "Structural Steel"

I need this to be a button that I press so there is no loop in the cell formatting, or else I would just use a basic excel function to reverse the words

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("C:C").Select
If MT = "Steel Structural" Then
Replace("Steel Structural", "Steel Structural", "Structural Steel") As String
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim C As Range
   Set C = Range("C:C")

   C.Replace What:="Steel Structural", Replacement:="Structural Steel"
End Sub
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!